# Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() on Vivo All Models having Os version 8.0

Tags: remoteserviceexception

getting below crash on All Vivo Models only after making all necessary suggested changes with notification channel in onCreate/OnStartCommand

```
 Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6671)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)

       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:818)

> Blockquote
```